# How a Logistic Regression model reacts if the probability of success and failure are exactly 0.5?

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-science, logistic-regression

We know that the default threshold for success in a Binary Classification of the Logistic Regression model is *> 0.5*.

I'm curious to know the output of this model if the predicted probability is exactly *0.5* for both Success and Failure. Can someone clarify me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From theoretical point of view - you can decide how to consider those samples with `p = 0.5.`

If you ask about the decision boundary of sklearn logistic regression implementation -

This is the predict method from the source code:

```
def predict(self, X):
    """
    Predict class labels for samples in X.
    Parameters
    ----------
    X : array_like or sparse matrix, shape (n_samples, n_features)
        Samples.
    Returns
    -------
    C : array, shape [n_samples]
        Predicted class label per sample.
    """
    scores = self.decision_function(X)
    if len(scores.shape) == 1:
        indices = (scores > 0).astype(np.int)
    else:
        indices = scores.argmax(axis=1)
    return self.classes_[indices]
```

You can see that they use argmax: `indices = scores.argmax(axis=1)` -- 
It means that if there are 2 classes with probability 0.5 it will take the first one (class 0); that`s the way argmax works.

```
scores = np.array([[0.5, 0.5]])
scores.argmax(axis=1)
Out[5]: array([0])
```

Answer (score 1):

To simply put, the model is not confident in making the decision. You can choose either of the class labels based on your problem -- do you want high precision or high recall ? However a more systematic way is to use ROC curve to find the optimal threshold value.

Comment: I understand that we can choose either of the class by setting the threshold. I am just wondering how the model reacts in such scenario?  Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by model reacts. Why does a model predict equal probabilities to both the classes ? because from the features it decides that both the classes are equally likely.  This is very much possible, if the true class distributions of the both classes overlap and you picked the data point which lies in this overlap.